# Pass variable outside of closure

Tags: javascript

```
var row, userIds = [];

con.query('SELECT * FROM cloud_users', function(err, rows) {
    if(err) throw err;

    for(i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {            
        row = rows[i];
        userIds[row.id] = 'TEST';
    }

    console.log(userIds);
});

console.log(userIds);
```

First `console.log` works but not the second. I need to have `userIds` outside of that closure. How?

Comment: To help make it clear before you read the linked QA: this isn't about closure or scope, but about asynchronicity.

Comment: This is sooo complicated... Thank you!